# animate audio spectrum onto a sphere using animation nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes

So, I'm trying to make an audio visualizer by applying a frequency spectrum onto a sphere.
(1st attempt at a visualizer using displace noise maps and audio baked to f-curves https://www.dropbox.com/s/b1dpi0hqu8icffz/visualizer%20v1_clip.mp4)

so, I'm using Animation nodes 2.1 and Blender 2.79b

I've been able to replicate this fantastic tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8PkdH_GXpQE, but translating the method onto a sphere is proving difficult.

can't seem to figure out how to get the data to work with a sphere. trying to get a ring of vertices and have them scale outwards?

Can anyone offer any guidance or assistance?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

I shall show how this can be done in 2.8, but the same applies for older versions. You just transform/multiply your transformations (In this case a circular distribution of matrices) with a scale matrix composed from the frequency bins on one vector component:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Brilliant. That sound spectrum node is new to me. I have never seen before.

Comment: clean and short node work, thank you for this. It's not exactly the solution, but it's very helpful.

Comment: @KevinMadden Can you clarify what you want exactly?

Comment: Was able to figure it out. I posted an answer w the nodes and result. :)

Answer (score 2):

I more or less figured it out

[image: enter code here]

I'm still getting some strange glitch errors where vertices seem to be shooting out to infinity, especially at lower sound falloff length values, but I'm very happy with how the effect is shaping up.

Comment: update: the top row of the matrix nodes are redundant, as you can just pull vertex data from input node on right side and go directly into offsets.

Also have realized that falloff data driven by sound really doesn't like when the length is lower than the index value of total frequency nodes used to bake sound. I think in AN 2.1 this would be "Count" field. Having falloff length greater than that integer value has fixed vertex glitches.